# How do I access environment variables in Vala?

Tags: environment-variables, vala

How do I access environment variables in Vala? (as above)  it seems simple, but I can't find how g_getenv() is mapped into Vala.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer lies in the bindings file.  Vala uses bindings (in .vapi files) for binding its constructs to the C language.  In this case you can grep through glib-2.0.vapi (on my system that is in `/usr/share/vala-0.10/vapi`), and you'll see that it is bound as:

```
unowned string? GLib.Environment.get_variable(string name)
```

It can be quite useful to have the location of the core VAPI files handy, because if you know the C name of a function you can just grep for it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, you went further than answering my question :)